# WooCommerce: Product Archive Conditional

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce

Is there a WooCommerce conditional to check if the current page is showing either sub-categories or products?

This question is not a duplicate as I wish to check if the current page is an archive of products, not a single product.

Comment: This question is not a duplicate as I wish to check if the current page is an archive of products, not a single product. Unfortunately both products and categories seem to use archive-product.php. Another option would be to check if a product is displayed on the current page somehow.

Comment: You can use `is_shop()`. It returns true when on the product archive page (shop).

Answer (score 1):

You can use [`is_product()`](http://woocommerce.wp-a2z.org/oik_api/is_product/) or [`woocommerce_product_subcategories()`](http://woocommerce.wp-a2z.org/oik_api/woocommerce_product_subcategories/)

Comment: I need to detect if the current page is an archive of products, not a single product. If the current page is the shop page or a category page I need to run some PHP, if the current page is an archive of products I need to run a different piece of PHP.

Comment: Essentially I just need to check if there are products on a page

Comment: All the WooCommerce conditionals you need are listed here https://woocommerce.com/document/conditional-tags/